# How to reduce time to wait systemd service?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a systemd service that change mac address every boot to wifi adapter. Systemd service works fine. I want the service not wait 1m 30sec when the wifi adapter is not plug in the usb.

How can I do that?

```
[Unit]
Description=macchanger on %I
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/macchanger -r %I
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: `TimeoutStartSec` is your friend. Send to something appropriate (it defaults to 90 secs, but don't set too low).

Comment: @stoney gives you a work-around, but you should check why there is 1m30 waiting time. Try to correct the cause

Comment: @stoney TimeoutStartSec=5 It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not start the unit as a dependency of `multi-user.target` in the first place. Instead, start it as a dependency **of the device itself.** Udev rules can be used to add Wants= dependencies to the device:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/90-macchanger.rules
ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan*", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="macchanger@$name.service"
```

This will cause the virtual `sys-…-wlan0.device` to have Wants=macchanger@.service, instead of multi-user.target having the same, so the service only gets started when the device appears.

Though if you do that, you don't *need* a .service anymore – you can just run macchanger from the udev rule directly. (Not possible for long-running services, but fine for small helpers.)

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/90-macchanger.rules
ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan*", RUN+="/bin/macchanger -r $name"
```

In fact this would be **better** than using a service, as it guarantees that the MAC change will be done before udev announces the device "ready" to other services.

Comment: My goal is mac address is changed before network is up. Do you think the second method is better?? I also say that I have one more udev rule that rename the long name of the wifi adapter from wlx****** to wlan0.

Comment: It is better because the software that brings network up will, usually, _wait_ for udev rules to finish processing (and, in fact, all "After=sys-subsystem-net" services will wait for udev rules too) so you can avoid racing against the network service.

Comment: @u1686-grawity and my method guarantees that the mac change before network is up, look at this https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MAC_address_spoofing

Comment: In your fist example do I have to write inside udev file every wlan adapter a different command? Example: `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="macspoof@wlan0.service" , ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="macspoof@wlan1.service" , ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="macspoof@wlan3.service" `???

Comment: I don't see where it guarantees that... No, you literally use `$name` as in the example (or `$kernel` or `%k`). See `man 7 udev`.

Comment: When I write `sudo systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg`  I see that `sys-…-wlan0.device` load after Networkmanager. In my systemd service `sys  wlan0` load before networok-pre.target. How can I do the same with your first example?

Comment: Thanks for your help but today I used the second (better as you said) example. Second example is the same with first. `sys-…-wlan0.device` load 5 systemd-service  from the end. My goal is change mac before anything network is up.  My systemd-service load `FIRST`.