# How systemd service restart if another systemd service restart?

Tags: debian, systemd

I have systemd 252 on Debian.  I want when the systemd service `systemd-hostnamed.service` restarts or starts to restart my `b.service`.

I used with no luck on my `b.service` the follow options.

```
After=systemd-hostnamed.service
Requires=systemd-hostnamed.service
BindsTo=systemd-hostnamed.service
PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service
```

How can I do that?

b.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Avoid NetworkManager sending hostname in DHCP request
Wants=network-pre.target
Before=network-pre.target

[Service]
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=80
RestartSec=15
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/hostname.py

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Comment: In systemd-hostnamed.service add Wants=b.service.   In b.service keep PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.service` needs two relationships with `systemd-hostnamed.service`:

- `PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service` will cause `b.service` to stop when `systemd-hostnamed.service` is stopped.
- `WantedBy=systemd-hostnamed.service` will cause `b.service` to start when `systemd-hostnamed.service` is started.

Both of these are used in a reset.

Adding the `PartOf=` relationship is trivial.  Just add that line to your `[Unit]` section.

```
[Unit]
PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service
```

`WantedBy=` can only be defined in the `[Install]` section, but you already have `WantedBy=sysinit.target`.  If you expect `systemd-hostnamed.service` to be started on `sysinit`, then you could just change this line.  Then `sudo systemctl {disable,enable} b.service`.

```
[Install]
# WantedBy=sysinit.target
WantedBy=systemd-hostnamed.service
```

If you want to keep `b.service`'s `[Install]` section unchanged, then an equivalent option is to add `Wants=b.service` to `systemd-hostnamed.service`.  This is done via overrides.  Use `sudo systemctl edit systemd-hostnamed.service` and set it to the following and save:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-hostnamed.service

[Unit]
Wants=b.service
```

This creates `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-hostnamed.service.d/override.conf` which adds the relationship to `systemd-hostnamed.service` without contaminating the original file deployed by `systemd`.

Comment: Thank you Stewart. I created /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hostnamed.service.d/override.conf and put `Wants=b.service` . Do I have to add in main b.service Unit section `PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service` ?

Comment: Yes.  `b.service` needs `[Unit]  PartOf=systemd-hostnamed.service` to stop when `systemd-hostnamed.service stops`.  `systemd.hostnamed.service.d/override.conf` needs `[Unit]  Wants=b.service` to trigger `b.service` to start.  Don't forget the `[Unit]` header in `override.conf`.

Comment: You are God!!! Thank you very much. Please would you like to read one unsolved post here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754854/how-to-reduce-time-to-wait-systemd-service

Answer (score 0):

Wrong layer.

```
[ipv4]
dhcp-send-hostname=false
```

in your profile on /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ will stop networkmanager from sending a dhcp hostname.

Comment: I know it. App doing this.